# Avoiding self assignment in std::shuffle

Tags: c++11, g++

I stumbled upon the following problem when using the checked implementation of glibcxx:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/debug/vector:159:error: attempt to self move assign.
Objects involved in the operation:
sequence "this" @ 0x0x1b3f088 {
  type = NSt7__debug6vectorIiSaIiEEE;
}
```

Which I have reduced to this minimal example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

struct Type {
        std::vector<int> ints;
};

int main() {
        std::vector<Type> intVectors = {{{1}}, {{1, 2}}};
        std::shuffle(intVectors.begin(), intVectors.end(), std::mt19937());
}
```

Tracing the problem I found that `shuffle` wants to `std::swap` an element with itself. As the `Type` is user defined and no specialization for `std::swap` has been given for it, the default one is used which creates a temporary and uses `operator=(&&)` to transfer the values:

```
  _Tp __tmp = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__a);
  __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
  __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
```

As `Type` does not explicitly give `operator=(&&)` it is default implemented by "recursively" applying the same operation on its members.

The problem occurs on line 2 of the swap code where `__a` and `__b` point to the same object which results in effect in the code `__a.operator=(std::move(__a))` which then triggers the error in the checked implementation of `vector::operator=(&&)`.

My question is: Who's fault is this?

- Is it mine, because I should provide an implementation for `swap` that makes "self swap" a `NOP`?
- Is it `std::shuffle`'s, because it should not try to swap an element with itself?
- Is it the checked implementation's, because self-move-assigment is perfectly fine?
- Everything is correct, the checked implementation is just doing me a favor in doing this extra check (but then how to turn it off)?

I have read about shuffle requiring the iterators to be ValueSwappable. Does this extend to self-swap (which is a mere runtime problem and can not be enforced by compile-time concept checks)?

### Addendum

To trigger the error more directly one could use:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vectorOfInts;
    vectorOfInts = std::move(vectorOfInts);
}
```

Of course this is quite obvious (why would you move a vector to itself?).
If you where swapping `std::vector`s directly the error would not occur because of the vector class having a custom implementation of the swap function that does not use `operator=(&&)`.

Comment: See [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=59603), especially the [last comment](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=59603#c5).

Comment: @dyp: And again my google fu let me down. How come I always enter search phrases that noone else seems to use? :( If I read this correctly they don't know either which ones fault it is?

Comment: Seems so. I searched for "attempt to self move assign" (with quotation marks), hoping that other people have quoted the same error message.

Comment: @Nobody:  I found your question informative anyway, +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The libstdc++ Debug Mode assertion is based on this rule in the standard, from [res.on.arguments]

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument.

i.e. the implementation can assume that the object bound to the parameter of `T::operator=(T&&)` does not alias `*this`, and if the program violates that assumption the behaviour is undefined. So if the Debug Mode detects that in fact the rvalue reference *is* bound to `*this` it has detected undefined behaviour and so can abort.

The paragraph contains this note as well (emphasis mine):

> *[Note:* If a program casts an lvalue to an xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g., by calling the function with the argument
>   `std::move(x)`), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary object. **The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the
>   argument was an lvalue.** *—end note]*

i.e. if you say `x = std::move(x)` then the implementation can optimize away any check for aliasing such as:

```
X::operator=(X&& rval) { if (&rval != this) ...
```

Since the implementation can optimize that check away, the standard library types don't even bother doing such a check in the first place. They just assume self-move-assignment is undefined.

However, because self-move-assignment can arise in quite innocent code (possibly even outside the user's control, because the std::lib performs a self-swap) the standard was changed by [Defect Report 2468](https://wg21.link/lwg2468). I don't think the resolution of that DR actually helps though. It doesn't change anything in [res.on.arguments], which means it is still undefined behaviour to perform a self-move-assignment, at least until [issue 2839](https://wg21.link/lwg2839) gets resolved. It is clear that the C++ standard committee think self-move-assignment should not result in undefined behaviour (even if they've failed to actually say that in the standard so far) and so it's [a libstdc++ bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR85828) that our Debug Mode still contains assertions to prevent self-move-assignment.

Until we remove the overeager checks from libstdc++ you can disable that individual assertion (but still keep all the other Debug Mode checks) by doing this *before including any other headers*:

```
#include <debug/macros.h>
#undef __glibcxx_check_self_move_assign
#define __glibcxx_check_self_move_assign(x)
```

Or equivalently, using just command-line flags (so no need to change the source code):

```
-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -include debug/macros.h -U__glibcxx_check_self_move_assign '-D__glibcxx_check_self_move_assign(x)='
```

This tells the compiler to include `<debug/macros.h>` at the start of the file, then undefines the macro that performs the self-move-assign assertion, and then redefines it to be empty.

(In general defining, undefining or redefining libstdc++'s internal macros is undefined and unsupported, but this will work, and has my blessing).

Comment: Wow, it won't get much more authorative than this. Just to let me summarize: An oversight in the standard that is about to be fixed led to overzealous checks in libstdc++' debug mode that are about to be removed. So we have to work around this until a fixed version is available.

Answer (score 6):

It is a bug in GCC's checked implementation. According to [the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), swappable requirements include (emphasis mine):

> 17.6.3.2 §4 An rvalue or lvalue `t` is swappable if and only if `t` is swappable with *any* rvalue or lvalue, respectively, of type `T`

*Any* rvalue or lvalue includes, by definition, `t` itself, therefore to be swappable `swap(t,t)` must be legal. At the same time the default `swap` implementation requires the following

> 20.2.2 §2 Requires: Type `T` shall be MoveConstructible (Table 20) and MoveAssignable (Table 22).

Therefore, to be swappable under the definition of the default swap operator self-move assignment must be valid and have the postcondition that after self assignment `t` is equivalent to it's old value (not necessarily a no-op though!) as per Table 22.

Although the object you are swapping is not a standard type, MoveAssignable has no precondition that `rv` and `t` refer to different objects, and as long as all members are MoveAssignable (as `std::vector` should be) the generate move assignment operator must be correct (as it performs memberwise move assignment as per 12.8 §29). Furthermore, although the note states that `rv` has valid but unspecified state, any state except being equivalent to it's original value would be incorrect for self assignment, as otherwise the postcondition would be violated.

Comment: [This](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/assignment-operators) (repeatedly) says `Self-assignment is not valid for move assignment.` which I would understand as: The checked implementation is correct in asserting.

Comment: There is nothing in the standard (or rather the publically available draft) which limits move assignment in such a way. Even if that is changed in the future, the default implementation of `swap` would then be incorrect (as it has to support any r or lvalue according to the standard). So in any case it is neither your fault, nor the fault of `std::shuffle`. A fixed version of `swap` would require one additional move construction. Or they would have to change the wording of swappable as well.

Comment: How do you get from "standard implementation of swap requires self-move-assignment to be valid" (type requirements quoted) to "said implementation is correct and makes self-move-assignment acceptable"?

Comment: Coud probably be reformulated a little as those are two separate things. The self move assignment is allowable as nothing is said to the contrary and it would otherwise violate the postcondition in Table 22, and swap must allow self-swap due to the "any rvalue or lvalue" part. As long as one accepts the first part as correct (and as the standard is written there is no reason not to), the implementation as used in GCC (and Visual Studio which is very similar) is allowable, otherwise it is not (and would require two temporaries instead of one and one additional move construction).

Answer (score 0):

I read a couple of tutorials about copy constructors and move assignments and stuff (for example [this](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-introducing-the-move-constructor-and-the-move-assignment-operator/)). They all say that the object must check for self assignment and do nothing in that case. So I would say it is the checked implementation's fault, because self-move-assigment is perfectly fine.

Comment: From what I have seen on a short glance I would not esteem the tutorial you linked too high. Regardless of the tutorial I am more interested in a definitive stance on this (like a standard quote).